# Why does adding a menu prevent the grid background from displaying?

Tags: wpf

I'm creating a simple window with an image for the background and with a Menu at the top. When I just had the Grid.Background block the image displayed. Once I added the Menu block, the image refuses to display. Why is that?

```
<Window x:Class="wpf_tutorial.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window" Width="521" Height="600"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="bkgd.jpg"/>
        </Grid.Background>

        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: your menu is the only item in the grid, and probably has it's own background. shouldn't your menu be OUTSIDE the grid ?

Comment: I thought so initially, but there can only be a single block within Window, so  nesting is required. I've tried with Grid nested inside Menu, and the same thing occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that your `Menu` is occupying the entire `Grid` since its dimensions are exactly the same as the `Grid`'s dimensions.  Thus, it will cover up the background image.  `DockPanel.Top` will only take effect if the element is within a `DockPanel`, and since you have a `Grid`, you're not seeing the desired effect.

You'll either have to place your `Menu` within a `DockPanel`, while also placing a `Grid` for your content:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="bkgd.jpg"/>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

... or place the `Menu` within a `Grid.Row` and set that row's `Height` to `Auto`, and similarly to the first example, I'd use a second `Grid` for the rest of the content:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Menu Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="bkgd.jpg"/>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to have a DockPanel, and simply dock your menu to the top.
It makes it easy to have as status docked to the bottom, and then let the main page take the rest of the page (so resizing is not an issues at all).

Here's an example to set you on the right path:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <DockPanel >
        <!--                                                           -->
        <!--    Your application menu. You have default commands, and  -->
        <!--    you can add your own commands. They work like nomrmal  -->
        <!--    button commands, so you can reuse them                 -->
        <!--                                                           -->
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Background="White"
          BorderBrush="Black"
          IsTabStop="False"
        >
            <MenuItem Header="_Default commands" IsTabStop="False">
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" />
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" />
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>


        <!--                                                        -->
        <!--   Last child fills the dockbar, so this will take      -->
        <!--    the "main" window and fill it.                      -->
        <!--                                                        -->
        <TabControl>

            <TabItem Header="One" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding One_VM}"  />
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Two" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Two_VM}"  />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```